# Use of array_agg and array string on inner query

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following piece of code:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS s CASCADE;  
CREATE SCHEMA s;

CREATE TABLE "s"."t1"
(
    "c1" BigSerial PRIMARY KEY,
    "c2" BigInt NOT NULL,
    "c3" BigInt
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);

INSERT INTO s.t1 (c2) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO s.t1 (c2, c3) VALUES (20, 10);
INSERT INTO s.t1 (c2, c3) VALUES (30, 10);

/* 1. */ SELECT t3.c1 FROM s.t1 as t3 JOIN s.t1 as t2 ON t3.c3 = t2.c2;

/* 2. */ SELECT t1.c1, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG((t2.c1)), ',') FROM s.t1 LEFT JOIN  s.t1 as t2
ON t2.c3 = t1.c2 GROUP BY t1.c1;

/* 3. */ SELECT c1, c2,
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG((SELECT t3.c1 FROM s.t1 as t3 JOIN s.t1 as t2 ON t3.c3 = t2.c2)), ',') 
FROM s.t1 t1
GROUP BY c1;
DROP SCHEMA s CASCADE;
```

The output for 1 query:

```
 c1 
 ----
 2
 3
(2 rows)
```

2 Query:

```
 c1 | array_to_string 
 ----+-----------------
   1 | 2,3
   2 | 
   3 | 
  (3 rows)
```

3 Query gives me a error:

```
   psql:/tmp/aggregate.sql:24: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

The 3 query uses 1 query as inner query. Is there a way to make Query 3 work with inner query as 1 rather than reverting to 2.

3 output should be same as 2.

I understand that the error message says query 1 when used as sub query of 3 cannot return more than one row.

Pardon my limited knowledge of database.

Answer:

```
 SELECT c1, c2,
 ARRAY_TO_STRING((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t2.c1) FROM s.t1 as t2 WHERE t2.c3 = t1.c2), ',') 
 FROM s.t1 t1
 GROUP BY c1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_agg` function is an aggregate function that needs to be used on columns, not a set.

Try this:

```
/* 3. */ SELECT c1, c2,
ARRAY_TO_STRING((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t3.c1) FROM s.t1 as t3 JOIN s.t1 as t2 ON t3.c3 = t2.c2), ',')
FROM s.t1 t1
GROUP BY c1;
```

Or use the `string_agg` function:

```
/* 3. */ SELECT c1, c2,
(SELECT STRING_AGG(t3.c1::text, ',') FROM s.t1 as t3 JOIN s.t1 as t2 ON t3.c3 = t2.c2)
FROM s.t1 t1
GROUP BY c1;
```

Comment: Both don't seem to work:
1. 
 ERROR:  function array_agg(bigint, unknown) does not exist
LINE 10:     ARRAY_TO_STRING((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t3.c1, ',') FROM s.t1 ...                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
2.psql:/tmp/aggregate.sql:43: ERROR:  function string_agg(bigint, unknown) does not exist
LINE 17:     (SELECT STRING_AGG(t3.c1, ',') FROM s.t1 as t3 JOIN s.t1...
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Thanks fo the help.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this on my phone last night. I put a few parameters in the wrong spot. Go ahead and try both of these again.

Comment: c1 | c2 | string_agg 
----+----+------------
  2 | 20 | 2,3
  1 | 10 | 2,3
  3 | 30 | 2,3

I get output from both queries.

Comment: No. I was looking for:

 1 | 2,3
  2 | 
  3 | 

2, 3 should have entries in the third colmn as 2.3

Comment: I am looking for output as Query 2

Comment: That's just because of the logic you've used for the subquery. I don't know your end goal is with this so I can't just give you a query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112311/discussion-between-gudge-and-michael-ambrose).

Comment: Sorry for not making things clear. I was looking for the output of 2 as inner query when used as a inner query.

Comment: I got the query. Thanks very much for your help.

 SELECT c1, c2,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t2.c1) FROM s.t1 as t2 WHERE t2.c3 = t1.c2), ',') AS snapshots
    FROM s.t1 t1
    GROUP BY c1;